# Edit Path of Sym-Link

Tags: symlink

I am curious if there is a way to set a symlink that could follow the below example format:

```
$> /tmp/../home/usr1/dir/oldFile
```

Specifically I want to create a file in another folder, say:

```
$> /home/usr2/newFile
```

that when I try to access it will resolve to the path above using a symlink rather than the most direct path (i.e. this one):

```
$> /home/usr1/dir/oldFile
```

Comment: I haven't tried what `--relative`/`-r` would do in that case, I am afraid it would make the symlink relative but look for the simplest relative path.

Comment: Your example is not that clear to me, I could have miss understood you, but I've tested it and it seems to do what you are looking for. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to do what I think you are looking for and it work without problems, for this I'm having doubts if this is what you asking:

I created a symlink (called it "the_symlink) that point to a file on my Desktop following a funny path:

```
ln -s /tmp/../home/phphil/Desktop/suzuki\ check\ list.ods /home/phphil/the_symlink
```

the destination path of the link is effectively the one setted. It's not modified by the system

```
ls -la /home/phphil/symlink
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 49 Oct 16 10:27 /home/phphil/symlink -> /tmp/../home/phphil/Desktop/suzuki check list.ods
```